# Sony, Camera API, stack overflow, QX100, feature requests, responses,

Tags: macos, camera, usb, sony, sony-camera-api

I saw some articles here about Sony camera, their APIs and so on.
Some people remaked that this is not a Sony Support Site, so yes thats
true, but not! At least if you look at the Sony Developer site,
Sony is pointing to Stack Overflow for Developer support!

https://developer.sony.com/2014/11/25/get-support-from-sonys-engineers-on-stack-overflow/

From the postings I saw here the issue is that they do not seem to be very active. :(

Others here in the forum suggested to call the Sony support, I tried that
with the generic Sony camera customer support in Europe. Friendly person, but very strict on, not passing over any developer support number or even accept feature requests or redirecting to some who would do so, so dead end.

I bought a QX100 and I really love the idea, but its implementation has just to many limits. The camera store said it sold very bad, which is sad. 
I see that it could have been cool for the life style shooter (guess thats a marketing
or usability point that this failed), but especially for the technical interested
people this could have been the perfect device.
I really would appreciate an last update to support manual mode and exposure readout.

It is great that the firmware was extended but some elementary features still lack:

- "M"-Mode for the camera to give full control (setExposureMode: Manual)
- extend the official control to non mobile devices
- read out exposure info
- camera control via USB
- wifi settings

  - changeable settings (like SSID, Keyword, encryption, network settings, ...)
  - join the camera into an existing Wifi-AP-Network, incl DHCP to join multiple cameras.
    which would also give the chance to join and control multiple cameras at the same time
  - if in the existing AP-Mode, support multiple clients at the same time
- udp video stream (also for life view)

Also the Info and API documentation needs to be updated, 
like the info which firmware versions support which features, 
or which cameras support the "Manual" "SetExposure" Mode.

So Robert McCain,  Joe Padre, Anna Aleryd (these Names are listed on the Sony site) some more activity here would be appreciated, incl. some info how to get in touch and file 
feature requests! Feel free to contact me.

Martin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a rant about Sony.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request for (and complaint to) Sony. This question is not directly about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Supported APIs overview is available here: https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Long answer: StackOverflow is intended for development questions, issues. Sony-APIs topic is not off-topic here, but the feature request post is. My personal recommendation is - post please here: https://developer.sony.com/2013/11/29/how-to-develop-an-app-using-the-camera-remote-api-2/

We appreciate your feedback and we keep updating the Camera Remote API with selected features.