# How to get full resolution through Liveview

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I am using SDK 2.3 and develop an Android application with AS-15 and 20 camera that is exclusively dealing with liveview.
I unable to obtain from Liveview a higher resolution than 640x360px, while the camera specs mention a 1920×1080/30P (HQ).

- How can I get the full resolution?
- Is this a limitation of the API ? Why?

  I've found that some (other) cameras implement get/setLiveviewSize and with the L it says

  > XGA size scale (the size varies depending on the camera models, and some camera models change the liveview quality instead of making the size larger.)
  >   What are the models with the highest liveview resolution?

Comment: I've posted my question in the Sony forum and received the following answer from @MarlinSony _Did you try calling "startLiveviewWithSize" passing in "L" as the param?_ 
The issue is that not my camera does not support this startLiveviewWithSize API. Also not clear from Sony documentation in the Reference guide what is the parameter impact: _"XGA size scale (the size varies depending on the camera models, and some camera models change the liveview quality instead of making the size larger.)"_

Comment: I would be glad to have a code sample demonstrating the "startLiveviewWithSize" API. It does not work on all camera I've tried even if they are listed as supporting Liveview size in https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Comment: Getting help from Sony of this camera api sdk is a *very* frustrating experience, no answers after 16 days... and I've tried through many channels, sony support email, sony support phone, sony forums.. I am  not the only one experiencing this lack of server, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454784/sony-camera-api-stack-overflow-qx100-feature-requests-responses